# Blazor WASM Prerendering crashes after navigating

Tags: c#, .net, signalr, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I have a Blazor WASM app running locally on .Net7 on Windows 10.
I want to add prerendering to the app, making it faster and more SEO friendly.

I've followed [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/prerendering-and-integration?view=aspnetcore-7.0&pivots=webassembly), and it does run and work. However, when I navigate back and forth in the website, the site freezes (and so does Chrome), yet there are no errors, nor messages in the Chrome Developer Tools.

Server Side Code:

**Program.cs**

```
...
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();


app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapControllers();
app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
```

**_Host.chtml**

```
@page "/"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
@using MyApp.Client
@namespace MyApp.Server.Pages
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@{
    Layout = null;
    
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <base href="~/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link href="css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="MyApp.Client.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <component type="typeof(HeadOutlet)" render-mode="WebAssemblyPrerendered" />    

</head>
<body>
    

<div id="blazor-error-ui">
    <environment include="Staging,Production">
        An error has occurred. This application may no longer respond until reloaded.
    </environment>
    <environment include="Development">
        An unhandled exception has occurred. See browser dev tools for details.
    </environment>
    <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
    <a class="dismiss"></a>
</div>
<component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="WebAssemblyPrerendered" />
<persist-component-state />

<script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

In the client, I have deleted **index.html**, as well as these two lines:

```
builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");
builder.RootComponents.Add<HeadOutlet>("head::after");
```

Update:
Apparently invoking an event Action in a service caused this. Weird because it was working fine on the regular Wasm project.